# Angular $http request inside of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use a directive in Angularjs in order to check if a user is themself in order to change the template accordingly.

For instance

```
    <li is-self >
        <a  ng-show="logged_in" ng-href="/users/{{user.public_id}}"> Settings </a>
    </li>
```

Admittedly this may not be the best approach to this problem, however I can't think of a better way to do it at the moment.

The problem I am having however is that I can not do an http request within the directive, thus I had to put it in a controller and reference it as a scope function i.e.

user_controller

```
    $scope.isSelf = ->
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/is_self/' + $routeParams.id}).
        success((data, status, headers, config) ->
            if data
                $scope.logged_in = true
        ).
        error((data, status, headers, config) ->
            console.log(data)
        )
```

user_module

```
    userModule.directive('isSelf', () ->
      link: ($scope) ->
        $scope.isSelf()
```

This technique poses a problem however, because the directive is being used across multiple files and multiple controllers. I think the solution that would be most appropriate would be just doing the request within the directive but that doesn't work because you can't seem to pass $http into it.

My ideal solution would be a combination of what I had like

```
userModule.directive('isSelf', () ->
   link: ($scope, $http) ->
      $http({method: 'GET', url: '/is_self/' + "3f8686589ad"}).
          success((data, status, headers, config) ->
              if data
                  $scope.logged_in = true
          ).
          error((data, status, headers, config) ->
              console.log(data)
          )
)
```

I am obviously fairly new to the framework, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you post your solution to your own question below and mark it as the accepted answer? It will remove it from the "unanswered" category.

Comment: couldn't you just create a controller that is bounded to your directive to allow it to always be created with the directive?

Answer (score -1):

Okay guys, I found the solution. Here it is for those who have the same problem.

Okay so after some more tinkering I realized that I guess I was going about it in the wrong way. I instead used a service per the suggestion below, here's the final code if anyone has the same problem and was wondering.

Module

```
userModule = angular.module('users', ["ngResource"])

userModule.factory('User', ['$resource', '$http', ($resource, $http) ->
    User = $resource "/users/:id", id: "@id",
        update: method: "PUT"
        destroy: method: "DELETE"

    User::isSelf = (id, cb) ->
        $http.get('/is_self/' + id).success (data) ->
            if data
                cb true

    User
])
```

Controller

```
StatsShowCtrl = ($scope, $location, $routeParams, User) ->
    User.get id: $routeParams.id, (user) ->
        self.original = user
        $scope.user = new User(self.original)

        $scope.user.isSelf $routeParams.id, (self) ->
            if self
                $scope.logged_in = true
```

HTML

```
<li ng-show="logged_in"> <a ng-href="/users/{{user.public_id}}"> Settings </a></li>
```